# Uniformly continuous function on totally bounded subset of complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity, complete-spaces

I have the following problem at hand:

Let $(X, d)$ be a complete metric space and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on any totally bounded subset of $X$.

My attempt is as follows:

I want to prove any totally bounded subset of complete metric space is compact. After that, proof will follow since for compact domains continuity implies uniform continuity. For this purpose, let $A$ be totally bounded subset of $X$ and let ${a_n}$ be any sequence in $A$. Since, $A$ is totally bounded, it has Cauchy subsequence, call ${a_{k_n}}$. Since X is complete, ${a_{k_n}} \rightarrow x$ for some $x$ in $X$. Now I am stuck here and cannot prove that $x$ lies in $A$.

How may I proceed after here? Or total idea from the beginning is wrong? If so, any idea on the proof?

Comment: "I want to prove any totally bounded subset of complete metric space is compact." This is not true. Consider $X = [0,1]$ and $A \subset X$ given by $A = (0,1)$.

Comment: In a complete space, **closed** + totally bounded $\implies$ compact

Comment: @JoseAvilez  thanks, then any idea on correct proof?

Comment: @under_mirror_ See my solution below.

Comment: @JoseAvilez sorry I didn't get how that $\delta>0$ also works on $A$? Can you more elaborate on this?

Comment: @under_mirror_ See my edit below.

Comment: @under_mirror_ **Do not** delete your question immediately after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, your approach would not work because totally bounded subsets of complete metric spaces need not be compact.

Instead, if $A$ is a totally bounded subset of a complete metric space $X$, then $\overline{A}$ is totally bounded and complete, hence compact. Thus, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\overline{A}$, which implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$.

To see this, note that $f$ being uniformly continuous on $\overline{A}$ means that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for $x,y \in \overline{A}$ if $d(x,y) < \delta$ then $d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$. So let $\epsilon > 0$ and get a $\delta > 0$ from uniform continuity on $\overline{A}$. Notice that if $x,y \in A$ with $d(x,y) < \delta$, then $x,y \in \overline{A}$ and also $d(x,y) < \delta$; it follows that for this choice of $\delta$ we have $d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$ (from uniform continuity on $\overline{A}$), which is precisely the uniform continuity of $f$ on $A$.

Comment: How do we know uniform continuity on closure of a set implies uniform continuity on set itself?

Comment: @under_mirror_ For a given $\epsilon > 0$, get the corresponding $\delta$ from uniform continuity on $\overline{A}$; you will notice that this $\delta$ also works on $A$ because there are fewer points $x,y \in A$ to test this on.

Comment: @under_mirror_ After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, instead of deleting it, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).